# ComboBox Field not updating when layer is selected

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I try to develop my plugin. The problem is that when the layer is selected in upper comboBox (QgsMapsLayerComboBox), in lower two boxes (Latitude, Longitude: usual ComboBoxes) shall appear fields correspoding with selected layers.

[image]

The problem is, that when I switch the layer in upper field, I can only choose the fields which are from the other layer...

[image]

On this picture, the fields "ID", "LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE" belongs to previously selected layer "coordinates" visible on 1st photo.

Here's my code of def_run of my plugin:

```
def run(self):

    self.dlg.layerCombo2.clear()
    self.dlg.layerCombo3.clear()

    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.layerCombo1.addItems(layer_list)
    self.dlg.layerCombo1.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)

    def field_select():
        self.dlg.layerCombo2.clear()
        self.dlg.layerCombo3.clear()
        selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.layerCombo1.currentIndex()
        selectedLayer = layers[selectedLayerIndex]
        fields = [field.name() for field in selectedLayer.pendingFields()]
        self.dlg.layerCombo2.addItems(fields)
        self.dlg.layerCombo3.addItems(fields)

    # This connects the function to the layer combobox when changed
    self.dlg.layerCombo1.currentIndexChanged.connect(field_select)
    self.dlg.show()
```

`

Comment: I cannot see **QgsFieldComboBox** objects implemented and **QgsMapLayerComboBox** is used in a wrong way (as a **QComboBox**).

Comment: **QgsMapLayerComboBox** objects automatically select all layers in your Map Canvas. You only need to have one **QgsFieldComboBox** object, with its respective connecting function, for when you select whatever layer automatically also select its respective fields.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I need to have two comboBoxes where I can choose 'X' and 'Y' column from point layer. How to implement QgsMapLayerComboBox and use it?

Comment: So what shall I do to make a field from which I have to choose a layer and then select fields from selected layer?

Comment: You can see that in my answer. If you need more Combo Objects add them with different name.

Comment: I added a **QgsMapLayerComboBox** directly in **QtDesigner** and it works as expected. However, object name is **mMapLayerComboBox**. You can watch it in image of my **Editing Note**.

Comment: In my second **Editing Note** you have the code for objects added with **QtDesigner**. I used default names suggested by **QtDesigner**.  It works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code snippet in my Test Plugin:

```
.
.
.
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox, QgsMapLayerProxyModel, QgsFieldComboBox
.
.
.

    def add_action(
.
.
.
        self.wcbL = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.dlg)
        self.wcbL.move(250, 80)
        self.wcbL.setFixedWidth(203)
        self.wcbL.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)

        self.wcbF = QgsFieldComboBox(self.dlg)
        self.wcbF.move(250, 120)
        self.wcbF.setFixedWidth(203)

        return action
.
.
.
    def select_layer_fields(self, vlayer):
        self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)
        field = self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        vlayer = self.wcbL.currentLayer()
        self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)
        self.wcbL.layerChanged.connect(self.select_layer_fields)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

I tried it out with two point layers; as it can be observed at following images.

With layer **points_test** (only one field):

[image]

When **random_points** layer was selected in **QgsMapLayerComboBox**, fields in this layer were automatically also selected in **QgsFieldComboBox** object (following image):

[image]

Plugin works as expected.

**Editing Note 1:**

Following image also contains a **QgsMapLayerComboBox** object added directly with **QtDesigner**. Its name is **mMapLayerComboBox**.

[image]

**Editing Note 2:**

When Combo Boxes are adding by using **QtDesigner** following code works as expected:

```
.
.
.
    def change_layers2(self):                                           #new function
        self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.clear()
        layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
        layer_list = [ layer.name() for layer in layers ]
        self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.addItems(layer_list)

    def select_layer_fields2(self, vlayer):                              #new function
        self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(vlayer)
        field = self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(vlayer)

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        vlayer = self.wcbL.currentLayer()
        self.wcbF.setLayer(vlayer)
        self.wcbL.layerChanged.connect(self.select_layer_fields)

        vlayer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()                           #new line
        self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(vlayer)                                     #new line
        self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.layerChanged.connect(self.select_layer_fields2)   #new line
.
.
.
```

It can be observed at following image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it is not working. I get the error: TypeError: add_action() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Comment: Also this error appears when I type def add_action():  " TypeError: add_action() takes no arguments (5 given)"

Comment: Instead **add_action**, put combo objects in **__init__** method.

Comment: Well, another error.  in __init__
       self.wcbL = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self.dlg)
   AttributeError: DMS2Point instance has no attribute 'dlg'

Comment: I build my plugins with 'Plugin Builder'. And you?

Comment: Plugin Builder. Bunch of tutorials. I spent ~ 24 hours and I have only 3 boxes and nothing really more. I made one step further and now I have error: in run
       vlayer = self.wcbL.currentLayer()
   AttributeError: DMS2Point instance has no attribute 'wcbL'

Comment: So, you should create a fourth object with my example code inside your plugin. When it works in it try to adapt it for your other objects.

Comment: What kind of object should i create and what name set? wcbL, wcbF?

Comment: I recommend you that start over with a new plugin because yours have several issues. Name wcbl is referred, in my case, for **QgsMapLayerComboBox**  and wcbF name is for  **QgsFieldComboBox**. These names  are not important in QtDesigner; only in PyQGIS.

Comment: Thanks. I started over but still have the same issue. With this line vlayer = self.wcbL.currentLayer(), instance has no attribute 'wcbL'

Comment: Can you hang in dropbox py file were __init__ method is in this new plugin?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=abc.py here it is

Comment: It worked somehow. But I see that You implemented Comboboxes directly into __init__ module. How to connect objects from QT Designer to code? It's easier to manipulate the objects there.

Comment: So the question is: how to connect the QgsFieldComboBox (named 'combo2') to QgsMapLayerComboBox (named 'combo1'). I know that I shall use setLayer() formula somehow from  this repository https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html. But how?

Comment: @icelandico - Maybe something like: `self.combo1 = self.dlg.layerCombo1`; `self.combo2 = self.dlg.layerCombo2`. This is how you would define objects created from Qt Designer.

Comment: @icelandico You need to change default names (something like **mMapLayerComboBox** or **mMapLayerComboBox_2**) for combo1 or combo2 in QtDesigner and use them in slot function (instead wcbL and wcbF in my code) for connecting.

Comment: @Joseph - This code does not connect any QgsFieldComboBox with QgsMapLayerComboBox...

Comment: None of these code examples are working. I'm not able to even load plugin with this code. Thanks for help. Plugin making terminated, thread closed.